# XAML Layout- how to add a WebKitBrowser below buttons inside a <Grid>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, presentation

I have the following XAML markup, which I am trying to use to display a `WebKitBrowser` below some buttons on the the GUI of my application:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                <Grid x:Name="browserGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="backBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_left.png" Height="30" Width="40" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="RefreshBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" >
                    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_loop3.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="printBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Image Source="C:\...\printer.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Name="referBtn" Click="referThis" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
                    <TextBlock>Refer</TextBlock>
                </Button>

                <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" Height="650" Width="900" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"></Grid>
                <!--/StackPanel-->
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
```

Basically, what I want to do, is display the buttons in a row above the `WebKitBrowser`, (which will be displayed inside the `grdBrowserHost`, to create a sort of 'navigation bar' inside the `<DockPanel>`

But for some reason, with what I'm doing above, I get the buttons displayed in the first few columns of the `<grid>`, and the browser displayed in the last column, but it's displayd 'next to' the buttons, rather than 'underneath, so the layout looks messy:

[image: app layout]

How can I fix the layout so that the `WebKitBrowser` content is displayed below the buttons, and not next to them? As you can see, I tried putting the `grdBrowserHost` grid (where the `WebKitBrowser` is displayed) inside the second row of the layout (i.e. one row below the row where the buttons are displayed), but this doesn't make any difference... anyone have any suggestions?

**Edit**

I tried setting the `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`, as suggested in the answer, but this just seemed to cause the `WebKitBrowser` to be displayed 'on top' of some of the other elements being displayed on my GUI, so that the layout now looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the browser is now displayed 'on top' of a couple of the buttons that I had previously added to my GUI, instead of underneath them, like I want it to, or beside them, like it was before...

I have set all of the buttons to: `DockPanel.Dock="Top"`, and the browser to `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"`... but for some reason, the browser is displayed on top of the right-most couple of buttons...

The line I'm now using to add the browser to the GUI is:

```
                    <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" Height="650" Width="900" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></Grid>
```

If I remove the `grdBrowserHost`'s `Row` & `Column`, then the web browser takes up the whole GUI, and completely hides the buttons I've added:

[image]

Any other suggestions?

Comment: what is `WebKitBrowser` here ? is that a `webbrowser` control ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Dock property of the controls you want to move around. So therefore:

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
                <Grid x:Name="browserGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="backBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_left.png" Height="30" Width="40" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="RefreshBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" >
                    <Image Source="C:\...\arrow_loop3.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Click="printBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Image Source="C:\...\printer.png" Height="30" Width="30" />
                </Button>
                <Button Style="{DynamicResource NoChromeButton}" Name="referBtn" Click="referThis" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Height="30" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
                    <TextBlock>Refer</TextBlock>
                </Button>

                <Grid x:Name="grdBrowserHost" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="650" Width="900" Margin="0,0,0,0" ></Grid>
                <!--/StackPanel-->
                </Grid>
            </DockPanel>
```

Note the DockPanel.Dock = "Bottom" in the grid named grdBrowserHost. You will also need to remove the grdBrowserHosts column/row property as you want its parent to be the dockpanel, not the grid.

I should ponit out that the Buttons you have will default to DockPanel.Dock="Left" as this is the default when not defined

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer- I've given your suggestions a go, but am still having issues regarding how the content of my application is displayed on my GUI- I've updated my OP to show the issues I get when trying what you've suggested. Anything else I should be doing here, or anything else I'm doing wrong?